# SMTP connect() failed in server hosting

Tags: php, server, gmail, codeigniter-3, phpmailer

I am confused sending e-mail with phpmailer in Codeigniter. This can't be done, because I didn't install SSL on my website. Error' is SMPT failed connect Can anyone answer?

This is my code:

```
private function _sendEmail($token, $type){
   
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host     = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'email@gmail.com';
        $mail->Password = '*****'; // password email
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port     = 587;

        $mail->setFrom('email@gmail.com');
        $mail->addReplyTo('email@gmail.com');
        $mail->addAddress($this->input->post('b'));
        $mail->Subject = 'test';
        $mail->isHTML(true);

        if ($type == 'verify') {
            $mailContent = '';
}else if ($type == 'forgot') {

}
$mail->Body = $mailContent;
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more what is the issue here? What do you mean by "This can't be done"? Do you get any errors or what?

Comment: I guarantee that isn't your error message. It might be _close_, but you didn't copy and paste it exactly: you typo'd "SMTP". Please _always_ make sure to provide _exact_ error messages. Details are important.